# Problems configuring my site to use a custom php.ini file for all directories

Tags: .htaccess, cgi, php

- PHP 5.2.17
- joomla 1.6.4
- 1and1 Linux shared server
- php is running as cgi

Hi, I am trying to use a custom php.ini throughout my website. I know I can put a php.ini file in each folder, but that would not be feasible.

I searched online and found the following method:

1 - create your custom php.ini file and put it inside path/to/your/website/cgi-bin folder

2 - create the following php.cgi file

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/local/bin/php5 -c path/to/your/website/cgi-bin
```

3 - upload php.cgi to /path/to/your/website/cgi-bin

4 - chmod +x php.cgi to make it executable

5 - include the following line inside .htaccess in my website root

```
Action application/x-httpd-php5 /path/to/your/website/cgi-bin/php.cgi
```

According to my understanding, after doing the above, php scripts on my website would start using my custom php.ini file instead of the default one.

Anyone can help? I spent a better part of the day trying to resolve this issue without success.

By the way, my account root (one level above my website root) has a .htaccess file with the following lines:

```
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php
```

Thank you.

## **UPDATE 9/2/2011 - 19:37**

tried including the following statement in .htaccess

```
SetEnv PHPRC /path/to/my/website/cgi-bin <- where my custom php.ini file is located.
```

According to this website it should have worked -> http://support.premiumreseller.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=85

But still nothing.

I will keep trying.

Any help appreciated!!!

## **UPDATE 2 - 9/3/2011 - 0:03 (WORKAROUND)**

So, I couldn't find a solution for my problem. I decided to create a small php script to create hard links to php.ini in each directory that has a php script.

See below the code in case you are curious:

```
<?php
define('ROOT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define('FILE_PHPINI', ROOT_DIR . "/cgi-bin/php.ini");
processdir(ROOT_DIR);

function processdir($path)
{
$FlagNoPHP = true;
$localPHPINI = $path . "/php.ini";
foreach ( new DirectoryIterator($path) as $file)
{
    if (!($file->isDot()))
    {
        if ($file->isDir())
        {
            processdir($path . "/" . $file);
        }
        else if ($FlagNoPHP && fnmatch("*.php*", $file))
        {
            $FlagNoPHP = false;
            if (!file_exists($localPHPINI))
            {
                link(FILE_PHPINI, $localPHPINI);
            }
        }
    }
}
if ($FlagNoPHP)
{
    if (file_exists($localPHPINI))
    {
        unlink($localPHPINI);
    }
}
}
?>
```

The above code looks inside each directory in my website and:

1 - if there is a php script and NO php.ini, creates a hard link to php.ini

2 - if there is NO php script and there is a php.ini, deletes the hard link (done in the last if of the function). I included this in order to clean up the filesystem of old php.ini files.

This worked for me.

I am still curious about an answer to my original problem.

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're taking the long way.  Just modify `.bashrc`:

```
export PHPRC="/Volumes/Mac_Daddy/web_curr/public_html/php_osx.ini"
```

Result:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/php5/lib  
Loaded Configuration File:         /Volumes/Mac_Daddy/web_curr/public_html/php_osx.ini  
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/php5/php.d  
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/php5/php.d/10-extension_dir.ini
```

Or create an alias:

```
alias myphp="/usr/local/php5/bin/php -c /somewhere/someplace/php.ini"
```

or better yet `man php`.